Some math symbols display an empty blue square
I'm using Lyx 2.4.1 with TexLive and Xetex on a PC with windows 11 installed (started using Latex stuff recently). When I write some math symbols (e.g <= symbol and tensor product symbol) they appear as an empty square (as can be seen in the picture below) while others (e.g >= symbol) appear normal in the Lyx GUI. When exporting the file to PDF, all of the symbols I tried look normal, so I'm suspecting its a problem with Lyx or with Fonts installed on my PC. ChatGPT suggested installing the "latin modern" font and changing it to the default math font in the preamble. it didn't work and gave me lots of errors of symbols missing when trying to compile so I undid the suggestion. Thanks ahead for any help and my apologies for any grammar mistakes, English is not my native language.


Welcome to TeX.SE!
